# Can I have doctype in iframe different from hosting page

Tags: html, iframe, doctype

Can I have doctype in iframe different from hosting page or iframe necessarily inherits doctype from hosting page?

```
<!DOCTYPE 1>
<html>
   <body>
      <iframe>
      <!DOCTYPE 2>
      </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think doctypes are inherited under any circumstance, so you should be okay specifying a different one in the iframe

Comment: I would guess they're totally independent of each other. We run ads in iframes and I would think our strict declaration might not be shared by 100% of these. That leads me to think that an HTML5 doctype wouldn't affect it either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can have a different doctype in the page that loads in the iframe.

The page containing the iframe and the page loading in the iframe are completely separate. The page in the iframe doesn't inherit anything at all from the page containing the iframe.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this. No problem (for example flash ads).